# ActiveStorage big file uploads triggers Google::Execution::Expired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-platform, rails-activestorage

While implementing ActiveStorage at work we found out that when uploading big file, 12GB ,  the operations hangs for about 10 minutes and the I get the error `Google::Execution::Expired` or sometimes `HTTPClient::SendTimeoutError: execution expired`.

I am running most uploads with a line like this:

`backup.file.attach(io: File.open("/my/file/path.ext"), filename: "myfilename")`

Is there a way to make the request to last longer or a way to circunvent this timeouts.

This strategy has worked fine, so far, for uploads of 4GB. It's just when I go overboard with the file size that this occurs. Time is not a problem on our side since this is a nightly task on a Cron job.

Answer (score 3):

The Google Cloud Storage client’s send timeout defaults to 1 minute or so. (You see a delay of 10 minutes because the client tries several times to resume the upload after encountering a timeout.) You can specify a different timeout in seconds in `config/storage.yml`:

```
production:
  service: GCS
  credentials: { ... }
  project: my-project
  bucket: my-bucket
  timeout: 120  # 2 minutes
```

Use `timeout: 0` to disable the send timeout.